# Ionic cannot open map app via ngHref on iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to do a map link in my app which when user click on it, it will open the native map app on iOS. When my code looks something like this `href="maps://maps.apple.com/?ll=1.5149818510303,110.35436153412"`, it works. However, when I put `ng-href="maps://maps.apple.com/?ll=1.5149818510303,110.35436153412"`, I will get `Failed to load webpage with error: The URL can’t be shown` error shown on XCode.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this to open the maps app on my ionic application:

JS:

```
$scope.openNavigator = function() {
  var geoString = '';

  if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
    geoString = 'maps://?q='+$scope.Latitude+','+$scope.Longitude+'';
  }
  else if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
    geoString = 'geo://?q='+$scope.Latitude+','+$scope.Longitude+'';
  }
  window.open(geoString, '_system');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="openNavigator()">
```

And it works perfect.